# Webpack: how do I build browser files for ES5 and server files for Node:current

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I am very new with Webpack. My new team is using it and I have never used it before.

We are building both a browser bundle and a server bundle.

**We are using Webpack version 4.41.2**

The browser bundle MUST transpile to ES5.

The server bundle is running on node 12.6.0 so it can have almost everything available. I do not want it to transpile.

in our package.json we have these two scripts:

```
    "build:browser": "webpack --config ./webpack/browser.babel.js",
    "build:server": "webpack --config ./webpack/server.babel.js",
```

The file `browser.babel.js` we have:

```
  module: {
    rules: base.module.rules.concat([
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader"
      },
```

The same thing is in the file `server.babel.js`.

I assume that both of these use the default `.babelrc` file which states:

```
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
```

But to turn off transpilation I needed to change to this:

```
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
```

My question is, how do I get the server build to use the settings that will prevent transpilation and get the browser build to use the setting that will transpile?

Is there a way to specify a different `.bablerc` file?

Is there a way to specify the settings inside the `server.babel.js` file?

Do we need to update to a newer version of Webpack?

Is there something else I need to do?

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass your server build thru babel at all.

Since it doesn't need to be transpiled you can leave it out of the webpack config script for that build.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no choice. The best I can do is to get rid of transpilation for Node.

Answer (score 0):

in `server.babel.js`,  you can pass in options to `babel-loader`. you can specify a specific config file: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#configfile
you might also want to set  `babelrc: false`

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          // set overrides here
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```